# Facebook page tab app "Content blocked" error

Tags: facebook, facebook-canvas

Facebook Page tab app gives 'This content is blocked. Contact the site owner to fix the issue.' from Morning. previously these were working for years. Does something changed on Facebook End for page tab apps.

But nothing has been mentioned [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/tabs/)

Is there any workaround for this. anyone else facing same kind of issue.

[image]

Comment: That looks like a browser error page, not something coming directly "from" Facebook. The browser console should probably have something to say about this.

Comment: @CBroe yes, we have console error related to frame-src "Refused to frame 'https://www.example.com/' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-src *.doubleclick.net *.google.com *.facebook.com www.googleadservices.com *.fbsbx.com ad.atdmt.com data: www.instagram.com *.vrich619.com *.fbcdn.net"." our application page is loading inside Facebook iframe. We are unable to control this.

Comment: Then it is probably a general bug. Check the FB bug tracker, and make your own report if there doesn't appear to be any currently open one for this issue.

Comment: @CBroe Thanks, We have created a bug for this issue https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/593062641823417/